# Forcing sequential processing in Haskell's Data.Binary.Get

Tags: performance, haskell, lazy-evaluation

After trying to import the basic Java runtime library rt.jar with language-java-classfile, I've discovered that it uses huge amounts of memory.

I've reduced the program demonstrating the problem to 100 lines and uploaded it to [hpaste](http://hpaste.org/41530/databinary_performance_proble). Without forcing the evaluation of `stream` in line #94, I have no chance of ever running it because it eats up all my memory. Forcing `stream` before passing it to `getClass` finishes, but still uses up huge amounts of memory:

```
  34,302,587,664 bytes allocated in the heap
  32,583,990,728 bytes copied during GC
     139,810,024 bytes maximum residency (398 sample(s))
      29,142,240 bytes maximum slop
             281 MB total memory in use (4 MB lost due to fragmentation)

  Generation 0: 64992 collections,     0 parallel, 38.07s, 37.94s elapsed
  Generation 1:   398 collections,     0 parallel, 25.87s, 27.78s elapsed

  INIT  time    0.01s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  MUT   time   37.22s  ( 36.85s elapsed)
  GC    time   63.94s  ( 65.72s elapsed)
  RP    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  PROF  time   13.00s  ( 13.18s elapsed)
  EXIT  time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  Total time  114.17s  (115.76s elapsed)

  %GC time      56.0%  (56.8% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    921,369,531 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  32.6% of total user, 32.2% of total elapsed
```

I thought the problem was the `ConstTable`s staying around, so I tried forcing `cls` in line #94 as well. But this only makes the memory consumption and the runtime worse:

```
  34,300,700,520 bytes allocated in the heap
  23,579,794,624 bytes copied during GC
     487,798,904 bytes maximum residency (423 sample(s))
      36,312,104 bytes maximum slop
             554 MB total memory in use (10 MB lost due to fragmentation)

  Generation 0: 64983 collections,     0 parallel, 71.19s, 71.48s elapsed
  Generation 1:   423 collections,     0 parallel, 344.74s, 353.01s elapsed

  INIT  time    0.01s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  MUT   time   40.60s  ( 42.38s elapsed)
  GC    time  415.93s  (424.49s elapsed)
  RP    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  PROF  time   56.53s  ( 57.71s elapsed)
  EXIT  time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  Total time  513.07s  (524.58s elapsed)

  %GC time      81.1%  (80.9% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    844,636,801 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity   7.9% of total user, 7.7% of total elapsed
```

So my question is basically, how do I force sequential processing of the files involved, so that after each one is processed, only the string result (`cls`) remains in memory?

Comment: How about you do some heap profiling and post that graph in your question.

Comment: I've added heap profiling output for both versions to hpaste.

Comment: Have you tried using the `cereal` package instead?  Just a thought, but strict bytestrings often help if you know the file is small enough.

Comment: I have two problems with `cereal`: One is that it doesn't seem to support floats in fixed byte order, the other is the lack of MonadFix instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit 2: I just realized your code does this:

```
stream <- BL.pack <$> fileContents [] classfile
```

Don't do that.  The `pack` functions are notoriously slow.  You'll need to find a solution that doesn't involve using `pack` to create a ByteString.

I'm leaving the rest of my answer because I still think it applies, but this is almost certainly the biggest problem.

Unfortunately I can't test this because I don't recognize all your imports.

If you only want the result `cls` to remain in memory, why don't you force it instead of forcing stream?  Change line 94 to

```
cls `seq` return cls
```

It may be necessary to use `deepseq` instead of just `seq`, although I have a suspicion that plain `seq` will be sufficient here.

However I think there's a better solution, and that's to use `mapM_` instead of `mapM`.  I think it's usually better style (and nearly always better performance) to create a function that does what it's supposed to with each result rather than returning a list.  Here, you can change your main function to:

```
main = do 
  withArchive [CheckConsFlag] jarPath $ do
    classfiles <- filter isClassfile <$> fileNames []
    forM_ classfiles $ \classfile -> do 
      stream <- BL.pack <$> fileContents [] classfile
      let cls = runGet getClass stream
      lift $ print cls
```

Now the `print` is lifted into the function passed to `forM_` for each classfile.  The value `cls` is used internally and never returned, so it's both fully evaluated and quickly GC'd on each iteration of `forM_`.

Making use of this style in a larger application may require some refactoring or even redesign, but the results may be worth it.

Edit:  If you're going to the trouble to redesign your code, you could use iteratees and avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: But in the real, actual program, my result would be the list of cls'es. Also, the second output is from stream `seq` cls `seq` return cls (sorry if I wasn't clear enough)

Comment: @Cactus, sorry but I just added a note to the top of my answer, check that.

Comment: Also, I know your result is the list of cls's, but I think you'd be better off creating a function that did something with each cls rather than creating a list of them.  But I don't think that's the most significant problem.

Comment: The modules I use come from Binary, data-binary-ieee754, bytestring, containers, missingh, and libzip (hope I didn't miss any)

Comment: What should I use instead of BL.pack? Would it help to use BS.pack and then BL.fromChunks?

Comment: In general BS.pack isn't an improvement over BL.pack.  In this case it might help or it might make it worse, depending on the implementation of LibZip.  I would first try using `deepseq` instead of `seq`.  I think part of the problem is that `seq`ing a string only forces the first character, and you want to force the entire string of `cls`, for which you'd need `deepseq`.

Comment: Thanks for the pkg list; missingh was the one I couldn't figure out.  Unfortunately I'm not going to be able to install LibZip either, so I still won't be able to test this.

Comment: Also, did you try using my altered "main" function?  If so, what sort of results did you get from it?

Comment: OK I've tried both the `deepseq` and the lifted version. The lifted version is much faster (85 vs. 54 seconds), and their memory consumption is the same (110 vs 118 megs, again the one using `lift . print` being the better one.

Comment: It seems like libzip does not play with bytestrings.  What if you unzip to disk and then read the bytestring using `BL.readFile`.  I conjecture that that will work much better, even if it is a bit less pretty.

Comment: @luqui, that was my conclusion too.  I was going to suggest using a parser that works with strings instead of Binary.  Although the real solution is to make LibZip work with bytestrings.

Comment: @Cactus, I think the lifted version is probably as close to optimal as you can get with the current design.  To get decent performance though, you'll need to do something that doesn't rely on `pack` (either strict or lazy), and your options are limited by the interface exposed from LibZip.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea to force evaluation of cls in line 94 was right. But I guess you're approach to do so wasn't successfull. See this [paste](http://hpaste.org/42466/databinary_performance_proble) for my version, which runs in ca. 40MB instead of 220MB.

The key is to force reduction to normal form of cls, which is done by rnf cls. And this has to happen before the call to return. Therefore:

rnf cls `seq` return cls

Alternatively, you could use Control.Exception.evaluate:
  evaluate $ rnf cls
  return cls

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions.

I think for my concrete problem, the solution will be to process .jar files in small chunks -- fortunately, inner classes are always in the same dir in the .jar file as their outer class, so there is no need to process all 50 megs in one run.

The only thing I couldn't quite understand is if it is possible to use libzip via enumerators, or would that need a new libzip implementation?